# How should I normalize the histograms for signal vs background study?

Tags: particle-physics, statistics, normalization

I am currently working on a signal vs. background study for some particle physics detector.
I am having a hard time understanding how I should normalize the signal/background histograms such that my analysis makes sense.
The idea of the study is to apply selections on the data in order to reduce the background while saving most of the signal.
Knowing that, what is the correct way of normalizing the histograms ?
At first I wanted to normalize them to the cross-section of each of the processes, but this does not take into account the number of events for a given selection.
The variables I have access to are :

- Signal/background cross section
- Signal/background number of events (varries for both and with the current selection)
- Integrated luminosity of the detector (150ab^-1)

The behaviour that I would expect from my normalization would be to see the signal efficiency (or significance) improving with each selection (provided my selections are good, of course)
I have also been wondering if I should use the total number of events (without any selection) or the number of events after a given selection for my normalization procedure.
Thank you.